# list message using ajax refresh

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, refresh, contextio

Hi I want to list emails using context io.But some times it returns zero messages and show blank page.So I decided to do it using ajax.

```
Step1 :First I take the count of messages
Step2 : Check if count>0
Step 3: if count>0 =>list message
Step 4 : else again take count and repeat step 3 and 4
```

My code is,

```
 $(function() {
      var contid='<?php echo $_GET['contextio_token'];?>';
      $("#ajaxloader").html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/ajax-loader.gif" style="width:60px;">');
      $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/gmailControl/countContext",
      data:"contxtid="+contid,
      success:function(result){
      if(result>0)
      {
    viewContextIO();
     }
      else
      {

           refreshContext();
      }

      }});

    });
    function refreshContext(){
          var contid='<?php echo $_GET['contextio_token'];?>';
      $("#ajaxloader").html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/ajax-loader.gif" style="width:60px;">');
      $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/gmailControl/countContext",
      data:"contxtid="+contid,
      success:function(result){//alert(result);
      if(result>0)
      {viewContextIO(); }
      else
      {
          setTimeout(refreshContext, 10000);
      }

      }});
    }
function viewContextIO()
{
     var contid='<?php echo $_GET['contextio_token'];?>';
  $("#ajaxloader").html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/ajax-loader.gif" style="width:60px;">');
      $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/gmailControl/view_contextIOmsg",
  data:"contxtid="+contid,
  success:function(result){//alert(result);
    $("#ajaxloader").html('');
   $("#contextmsgcnt").html(result);
  }});

}
```

But some times it takes more than 30 refresh and finally got a `500 internal server error`.
I think it is the problem of server overloading.Is it a correct logic or is any other solution?any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing messages when using one of the API libraries then there's likely a problem with the account connection. Too many requests to the server can cause the email provider to throttle access to the account from outside services.

If you're still having problems just email us at support@context.io.